# How can I get a list of all the projects in our Rally instance via the REST API?

Tags: rally

How can I query our Rally instance for all of our available projects?

---

*Output from REST call* https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.29/subscription.js?fetch=Workspaces,Name,Projects&pretty=true

```
...
"Workspaces":     [
            {
        "_rallyAPIMajor": "1",
        "_rallyAPIMinor": "29",
        "_ref": "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.29/workspace/1376977801.js",
        "_objectVersion": "10",
        "_refObjectName": "Workspace 1",
        "Name": "Workspace 1",
        "Projects": [            {
            "_rallyAPIMajor": "1",
            "_rallyAPIMinor": "29",
            "_ref": "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.29/project/2510231094.js",
            "_objectVersion": "3",
            "_refObjectName": "Layout",
            "Name": "Layout",
            "_type": "Project"
        }],
        "_type": "Workspace"
    },
            {
        "_rallyAPIMajor": "1",
        "_rallyAPIMinor": "29",
        "_ref": "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.29/workspace/1462743357.js",
        "_objectVersion": "8",
        "_refObjectName": "Bugzilla Workspace",
        "Name": "Bugzilla Workspace",
        "Projects": [            {
            "_rallyAPIMajor": "1",
            "_rallyAPIMinor": "29",
            "_ref": "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.29/project/2510231094.js",
            "_objectVersion": "3",
            "_refObjectName": "Layout",
            "Name": "Layout",
            "_type": "Project"
        }],
        "_type": "Workspace"
    },
```

...

---

**Update #2**
The user account being used for the API calls is indeed a subscription admin. I tried a few things with our admin to try and narrow down the problem as to what is occurring and noted a few things:

1. The projects that are getting returned in the call, are not projects that the api user is a team member of
2. When we assigned a story to the api user and refreshed the result of the REST call, the projects that were returned in every workspace were identical and seemed to be all of the projects from the given workspace of the project that we assigned the story from. For example, I've pasted the top part of a return: http://khayes.privatepaste.com/cfc730dcf8
3. It appears this particular REST call has a bug in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be possible by querying on type 'Subscription'.  Make sure you include Workspaces and Projects (and any other data you might want like Name) in your Fetch.

```
https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.29/subscription.js?fetch=Workspaces,Projects,Name&pretty=true
```

The results should look something like this:

```
{
    _ref: "/subscription/1.js",
    _refObjectName: "My Subscription",
    Workspaces: [
        _ref: "/workspace/2.js"
        _refObjectName: "My Workspace",
        Projects: [
            {
                _ref: "/project/3.js"
                _refObjectName: "Project 1"
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

Comment: What would the REST URI look like?

Comment: Unfortunately this did not provide me the list of projects in our system. It only showed all of the workspaces, but each with the same, one project nested below. See my above edit...

Comment: That's strange- all of the workspaces you have permission to should be returned and all projects beneath those as well...

The account you are connecting with- what type of permissions does it have?  Workspace admin?  Individual project permissions?

It's possible this is a bug, in which case it should be submitted to Rally Support

Comment: So that's an excellent question. The user is one we created specifically for interacting with the api. I will ask one of our admins this morning what permissions are setup. Thanks!

Comment: It does appear there is an odd bug going on here. We tested a few more things which I outlined a above and we got very bizarre results. I've accepted this answer in the meantime and will talk with Rally support.

Comment: How to query this in the .NET API? Something like:

Comment: Request request = new Request("Subscription");
            request.Fetch = new List<string>() { "Workspaces", "Projects", "Name" };
          QueryResult queryResult = restApi.Query(request);

returns a different result...

Answer (score 1):

The REST URL would look like this

https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.29/subscription?fetch=Workspaces,Name,Projects

Answer (score 1):

I tried in postman with basic authentication: username and password of rally:
All APIs are inter related : let us see step by step and always notice the _ref in your response.

Step 1: First you want the subscription.

> https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/subscription?fetch=Workspaces,Name,Projects

It will return subscription ID suppose it is X.

Step 2: Find the workspaces in that subscription. Put X value as subscription shown below.

> https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/Subscription/X/Workspaces

It will return the workspace id. Let us say it Y.

Step 3: Find the projects in the workspace.

> https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/Workspace/Y/Projects?fetch=ObjectID

There will be URLs in the response which refers to your projects associated to your workspace.

OR,

if you know your workspace ID then use below api: your_WS_id= your workspace ID in below request. just replace this.

> https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/Workspace/your_WS_ID/Projects?fetch=Name

I hope it helps.