# Display All Rally Projects in a drop down menu in Cloud 9 using JS

Tags: javascript, rally, cloud9-ide

I am new with Rally App builder and I need some assistance with the use of the API. In Cloud 9 I want to create a drop down menu that displays all my projects. It should be pretty simple to do but I am unaware of what API to use to fetch this data. Anyone with wise experience can help? Thanks alot!

Comment: This question explains how to get all the projects from rally: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9267370/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-all-the-projects-in-our-rally-instance-via-the-rest-api.

Answer (score 0):

That comment above references the deprecated 1.x series of the WSAPI.

In SDK 2.0 you should be able to use this component:
https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0/doc/#!/api/Rally.ui.combobox.ProjectComboBox